# Apache rewrite need seperate rules for https?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, centos8

On a centos8 server I created a file called /etc/httpd/conf.d/rewrite.conf with these contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.othersite.com  [L,R]
```

If I goto http://myserver.com it gets redirected to https://www.othersite.com as expected. But, if I goto https://myserver.com its not being redirected. I just get the regular index.html. There's a valid cert installed.

Should it work like that or does apache need additional rewrite rules in the SSL virtual host definition?

Answer (score 0):

> does apache need additional rewrite rules in the SSL virtual host definition?

Yes.

Your `rewrite.conf` file needs to be *included* in both places, since the vHost host *overrides* the main server config (where I assume you have defined the site for port 80 by the sounds of it). (Although port 80 should ideally be defined in its own vHost container.)

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.othersite.com  [L,R]
> ```

Note that this redirects all requests to the root of `othersite.com` - is that the intention. (Your capturing subgroup in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* suggests otherwise.)